# How to approach this design problem

Tags: java, architecture

***Scenario***

One warehouse, suppliers and consumers. One supplier can produce only one type of stuff. One consumer can also consume only one type of stuff. The warehouse knows about suppliers and consumers, but none of them is aware about each other.

How can I Design the interfaces for all actors in this scenario and simulate it  using generics to demonstrates how the warehouse works with several suppliers, consumers and different types of stuff.

Comment: for me, it's a bit hard to say without a concrete example of what's the program is supposed to do. Intuitively, I'd say you don't even need interfaces or generics because the differences between the objects can be sufficiently characterized by properties.

Comment: I wanted to implement using Generics and the program should explain how warehouse working with several suppliers and consumers and different types of stuffs, it's basis is normal business of how warehouse, customer and suppliers work in real life.

Comment: What are the use cases describing the interations between them?

Comment: Suppliers supplies good to warehouse and warehouse supplies good to the consumer, consumer and suppliers have no direct interactions and they always go through warehouse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you want to have a `Supplier` class and a `Consumer` class that implement generics so that you might have implement `Supplier<Clothes>` or `Consumer<Food>` or something else in your `Warehouse` class?

You might try something along the lines of this. This is more likely implementing a generics factory, I suppose.

```
public class Supplier<T>{
    //You might decide you need an actual constructor that does something
    public Supplier(){}

    public T supplyItem(){
        return new T();
    }
}
```

Consumer might look like...

```
public class Consumer<T>{

    private int consumeCount = 0;

    //You might decide you need an actual constructor that does something
    public Consumer(){}

    public void consumeItem(T item){
        consumeCount++;
    }

    public int consumeCount(){
        return consumeCount;
    }
}
```

And finally, your Warehouse could include something like...

```
Supplier<Integer> integerSupplier = new Supplier<Integer>();
Consumer<Integer> integerConsumer = new Consumer<Integer>();
Integer i = integerSuppler.supplyItem();
integerConsumer.consumeItem(i);
integerConsumer.consumeItem(integerSupplier.supplyItem());
System.out.println(integerConsumer.consumeCount());
```

Which we'd expect to print "2". You might also change your consume methods to take an instance of `Object` instead of `T`, and use `instanceOf` to either deal with it or say "Can't consume that, not my thing." There are some things you should be careful of with `instanceOf` though, so if it's not required to be that robust I wouldn't worry about it. http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=31 has a nice explanation of why.

EDIT: It might look like Consumer and Supplier are interacting with each other, especially when you have a line like `integerConsumer.consumeItem(integerSupplier.supplyItem());`, but it's important to note that the Consumer and the Supplier aren't actually interacting with each other there. the Supplier is simply generating a new Object, and the Consumer is taking that as an argument. While Warehouse knows of the existence of the Consumer and Supplier, the Consumer does not know of the existence of Supplier and vice versa.

Comment: Warehouse class looks more like main() method.

Comment: I included that snippet of code to show how `Consumer` and `Warehouse` could be invoked. I imagine it will be up to Rachel to specify exactly what is needed in Warehouse :)

Answer (score 0):

have you thought of a 2-dimensional matrix

- Producer
- Consumer

The content of the matrix defines the "stuff" they produce/consume and also if they are allowed to have an relation.

Would that work?

Answer (score 0):

Warehouse

```
public enum ITEMTYPE //known and public
Map<ITEMTYPE, count> items
Map<Supplier, ITEMTYPE> suppliers

registerSupplier(Supplier)
addItems(Supplier, count)

registerConsumer(Consumer)
consumeItems(Consumer, count)
```

Supplier

```
ITEMTYPE type
ITEMTYPE getType()
```

Consumer

```
ITEMTYPE type
ITEMTYPE getType()
```

The way to use it:

```
Warehouse w = new Warehouse()
Supplier s1 = new Supplier(ITEMTYPE pens)
w.registerSupplier(s1)
w.addItems(s1, 10) // Update the data structure in warehouse with validations

Consumer c1 = new Consumer(ITEMTYPE pens)
w.registerConsumer(c1)
w.consumeItems(c1, 5) // Update the data structure in warehouse with validations
```